SQL restore single table from backup database. Columns has timestamp and I must use IDENTITY_INSERT
I must restore single table from backup.
But table has identity column Id and timestamp
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Production].[dbo].[SystemInfos] ON
INSERT INTO [Production].[dbo].[SystemInfos]
(ID, Ident, Value, Data, Stamp)
SELECT * FROM [Archive].[dbo].[SystemInfos]
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Production].[dbo].[SystemInfos] OFF

When use this query I have error

Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column. Use INSERT
with a column list to exclude the timestamp column, or insert a
DEFAULT into the timestamp column.

When use query like this
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Production].[dbo].[SystemInfos] ON
INSERT INTO [Production].[dbo].[SystemInfos]
SELECT * FROM [Archive].[dbo].[SystemInfos]
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Production].[dbo].[SystemInfos] OFF

I have error

An explicit value for the identity column in table
'Production.dbo.SystemInfos' can only be specified when a column list is
used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

How to import tables by modifying id and set timstamp?

Are you (i.e. any programs) using the "timestamp" column? Because they typically shouldn't. Basically, you'll need to use the first version, and exclude the timestamp column from the insert statement.

The errors are quite specific here; what about them are unclear?

You need to explicitely specify the columns on both sides:
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Production].[dbo].[SystemInfos] ON
INSERT INTO [Production].[dbo].[SystemInfos]
(ID, Ident, Value, Data) -- specify columns you're inserting to
SELECT ID, Ident, Value, Data -- specific the columns you're inserting from
FROM [Archive].[dbo].[SystemInfos]

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Production].[dbo].[SystemInfos] OFF

Generally, it's always good to:

Specify insert columns, regardless of identity etc. This prevents issues later when you add another column to a table but don't update your insert.
Specify select columns instead of select *. This is same as previous point, plus, you control the column order

